# make4ht/mk4ht does not make breaks between words

Tags: make4ht

make4ht/mk4ht produces an odt file with no breaks between words after the 1st footnote. But it used to be ok just recently. What can be the problem? Disabling `hyphenat' package does not help.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek.ancient,latin,english,german,french,dutch,italian,spanish,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=gost-footnote,language=auto,autolang=other,autocite=footnote,citetracker=true,ibidtracker=false,opcittracker=false,citereset=chapter,sorting=none,notetype=foot+end]{biblatex}
%citepages=omit
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}

\usepackage{hyphenat}
\setsecnumdepth{section}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setsecheadstyle{\large\textbf\centering}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\centering}
\hyphenpenalty=1000
\tolerance=5000
\clubpenalty = 11000
\widowpenalty = 11000
\interfootnotelinepenalty = 10000
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage[twoside=false,bindingoffset=1cm,left=2cm,right=1cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{microtype}


\interfootnotelinepenalty=25
\raggedbottom

\setlength{\parindent}{30pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.15\baselineskip}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@book{Tolstoy:1900,
title = {Resurrection},
author = {Leo Tolstoy},
location = {St-Petersburg},
date = {1900},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Как ни старались люди, собравшись в одно небольшое место несколько сот тысяч, изуродовать ту землю, на которой они жались, как ни забивали камнями землю, чтобы ничего не росло на ней, как ни счищали всякую пробивающуюся травку, как ни дымили каменным углем и нефтью, как ни обрезывали деревья и ни выгоняли всех животных и птиц, — весна была весною даже и в городе. Солнце грело, трава, оживая, росла и зеленела везде, где только не соскребли ее, не только на газонах бульваров, но и между плитами камней, и березы, тополи, черемуха распускали свои клейкие и пахучие листья, липы надували лопавшиеся почки; галки, воробьи и голуби по-весеннему радостно готовили уже гнезда, и мухи жужжали у стен, пригретые солнцем. Веселы были и растения, и птицы, и насекомые, и дети. Но люди — большие, взрослые люди — не переставали обманывать и мучать себя и друг друга.\autocite{Tolstoy:1900} Люди считали, что священно и важно не это весеннее утро, не эта красота мира Божия, данная для блага всех существ, — красота, располагающая к миру, согласию и любви, а священно и важно то, что́ они сами выдумали, чтобы властвовать друг над другом. 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean hyphenation is turned off, or that literally there are no breaks sothateverythingiscrushedtogetherlikethis? Either way, provide a [minimal working example](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=latex+stackexchange+minimal+working+example) if you can?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You should provide a small complete document which reproduce your problem ...

Comment: There are literally no breaks.

Comment: I get `! LaTeX Error: Unicode character ́ (U+0301)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.`

Comment: from make4ht you get a single line _in the source_ just as you have a single line in your tex source but it line wraps to the window, eg [this output in firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBfeL.png)

Comment: Do you mean that there are no spaces in the text after footnote? I cannot reproduce that, everything looks as expected with current TeX4ht sources.

Comment: Same here. Once I remove the character that causes the error David mentioned, the resulting document with `make4ht -f odt filename.tex` seems to have the appropriate spaces everywhere. (I can't read Russian so I don't know if there's a problem I'm missing, but it looks OK.)

Comment: Thank you, there must be something wrong with my texlive installation. It was good to know the problem was not in the code.

Comment: @StarostinDmitri you could try to update to TL 2022, to have newest files. I hope it should fix it.